# Prove an n x n square can be tiled with 3x1 slabs and one 1x1 slab (divide and conquer)

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

If I have a wooden slab of size 3m x 1m, and the wooden slab can tile any n x n room with such slab if n is divisible by 3. Is it true that for every n> 3 that is not divisible by 3, one can tile an n x n square with such slab and a single 1m x 1m slab? I know that it's possible. However, how can I prove this using divide and conquer?

I'll provide an example for clarification. If I have a 4x4 room, I can tile all the room with 3x1 wooden slabs and one 1x1 wooden slab.

[image: 4x4 room]

Comment: Interesting: Given `n=3a+b` where `b` is 0,1,2, then `n*n` is either a multiple of 3 or 1 more.  So could be solvable.  Yet "how can I prove this using divide and conquer?" is a fairly broad question for a programming site.  What have you tried?

Comment: I had the same thought, it's just an assignment which I have at uni, I solved it using man techniques. However, I couldn't solve it using divide and conquer, which is required in the question.

Comment: Your 4x4 picture can be extended to cover the (3n+1)x(3n+1)  case by dividing up the square into a 3n x 3n top left square and a vertical 3nx1 rectangle and a horizontal 3nx1 rectangle and the 1x1 bottom right square. 5x5 is doable by putting the 1x1 in the middle and dividing up the rest into 2x3 rectangles. I'm stuck after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cover them all. My apologies for not drawing pictures but alas I don't have the tools.

Let the square be of side K

a/ If K = 3n + 1 then we divide the square into a top left 3n x 3n square, a vertical 3n x 1 rectangle, a horizontal 3n x 1 rectangle and a 1 x 1 square at the bottom right

b/ if K = 3n+2 (and n>0) then we divide the square into a 2 x 3n rectangle along the top (starting at the left of the KxK square), a 3n x 2 rectangle along the right (starting at the top of the KxK square), a 2 x 3n rectangle along the bottom (starting at the right of the KxK) and a 3n x 2 rectangle along the left (starting at the bottom of the KxK), leaving a 3n+2-4 sided central square. But 3n+2-4 = 3n-2 = 3(n-1)+1 so by a/ we can cover that.

Answer (score 1):

> However, how can I prove this using divide and conquer?

When `n` is large than 5, simply enough to fill the bottom 3 rows and right 3 columns and then solve the remaining `n-3` square.

```
. . . . . .  A A A
. . . . . .  B B B
. . . . . .  C C C
. . . . . .  D D D
. . . . . .  E E E
. . . . . .  F F F

a b c d e f  x y z
a b c d e f  x y z
a b c d e f  x y z
```

Only need to solve `n==3, 4, 5`

---

The recursive idea is simple for the 3,4,5 cases: At each tile in the square, if the tile is empty and a horizontal or vertical bar fits, place it and recurse.  Then undue the bar and try the next square.

If there was no empty tiles, success!

**Warning there is a bug or two in the code**

I left some bugs in so as not give give away the answer.  A careful read should find them.

The below is not highly efficient, yet gets the 3,4,5 job done.

```
void tile3_print(int n, char square[n][n]) {
  puts("");
  for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
      printf("%c ", square[row][col] ? square[row][col] : ' ');
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  fflush(stdout);
}

bool tile3_helper(int n, char square[n][n], char ch) {
  //tile3_print(n, square);
  assert(ch <= 127);
  bool all_squares_marked = true;
  for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
      if (square[row][col] == 0) {
        all_squares_marked = false;
        if (col + 2 < n && square[row][col + 1] == 0
            && square[row][col + 2] == 0) {
          square[row][col] = square[row][col + 1] = square[row][col + 2] = ch;
          bool success = tile3_helper(n, square, (char) (ch + 1));
          square[row][col] = square[row][col + 1] = square[row][col + 2] = 0;
          if (success) {
            return true;
          }
        }
        if (row + 2 < n && square[row + 1][col] == 0
            && square[row + 2][col] == 0) {
          square[row][col] = square[row + 1][col] = square[row + 2][col] = ch;
          bool success = tile3_helper(n, square, (char) (ch + 1));
          square[row][col] = square[row + 1][col] = square[row + 1][col] = 0;
          if (success) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (all_squares_marked) {
    tile3_print(n, square);
  }
  return all_squares_marked;
}

bool tile3_helper1(int n, char square[n][n], char ch) {
  bool all_sqaures_marked = true;
  for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
      all_sqaures_marked = false;
      square[row][col] = ch;
      if (tile3_helper(n, square, (char) (ch + 1))) {
        return true;
      }
      square[row][col] = 0;
    }
  }
  return all_sqaures_marked;
}

bool tile3(int n) {
  assert(n >= 3);
  char square[n][n];
  memset(square, 0, sizeof square);
  bool success = n % 3 ? tile3_helper1(n, square, 'A') : //
                         tile3_helper(n, square, 'A');
//  tile3_print(n, square);
  return success;
}

int main(void) {
  for (int i = 3; i < 7; i++) {
    int success = tile3(i);
    printf("Success %d = %d\n", i, success);
  }
}
```

Output (with corrected code)

```
A A A 
B B B 
C C C 
Success 3 = 1

A B B B 
C C C D 
E E E D 
F F F D 
Success 4 = 1

B B B C D 
E E E C D 
F G A C D 
F G H H H 
F G I I I 
Success 5 = 1
```